# What does the String classes compareTo() method return

Tags: java, string, compareto

In the Java API on oracles [website](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29): "compareTo Returns: "the value 0 if the argument string is equal to this string; a value less than 0 if this string is lexicographically less than the string argument; and a value greater than 0 if this string is lexicographically greater than the string argument." "

Here is an if statement:

```
String a = "abd";
String b = "abc";

if(a.compareTo(b) >= 1)
```

returns true
since string a is greater, lexicographically.

My question is, does the compareTo always return a 0, 1, or -1? or does it return the actual *amount* that the string is greater than or less than the string argument.

So in the above if statement, since "abd" is one greater than "abc" is it returning 1?

Comment: Just try it : `System.out.println(a.compareTo(b))`

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Those answers aren't safe; the return value (though nearly always -1, 0, or 1) is implementation-dependent.

Comment: You should not assume more than what the documentation says, and the documentation only says: 0, less than 0 or greater than 0. You can look at the implementation, but on a different Java implementation it might be different and your program won't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as you're concerned, there's no telling what the magnitude of the `compareTo` return value is, just the sign. In practice, most `compareTo` implementations will return -1, 0, or 1, but the contract specifically says positive or negative, and you should write your code accordingly (e.g., using `int compare = a.compareTo(b); if(compare > 0) {...} else...`).

Comment: This was a simple example, but I would like to know if it is actually calculating the difference of the two strings.

Comment: You can look at [the source for the OpenJDK `String` class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.compareTo%28java.lang.String%29). In this case, yes, it's directly subtracting the two `char` values to avoid having to branch.

Answer (score 5):

According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29

> In this case, compareTo returns the difference of the two character values at position k >in the two string -- that is, the value:
>
> ```
> this.charAt(k)-anotherString.charAt(k)
> ```
>
> If there is no index position at which they differ, then the shorter string lexicographically precedes the longer string. In this case, compareTo returns the difference of the lengths of the strings -- that is, the value:
>
> ```
> this.length()-anotherString.length()
> ```

For the last case, for the lengths of the `String`, by documentation that seems it can return other than -1, 0, 1

Comment: it does seem like that! but they aren't specific enough to make me feel comfortable relying on this assumption.

Comment: If the documentation is "lying" about the default implementation, yes then you can't be confortable

Answer (score 0):

[Falmarri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41115079/what-does-compareto-actually-return) fully answered this question; as opposed to only indicating the conditions in which the return value would be positive, negative or zero.

"This is the definition of lexicographic ordering. If two strings are different, then either they have different characters at some index that is a valid index for both strings, or their lengths are different, or both. If they have different characters at one or more index positions, let k be the smallest such index; then the string whose character at position k has the smaller value, as determined by using the < operator, lexicographically precedes the other string. In this case, compareTo returns the difference of the two character values at position k in the two string -- that is, the value:

this.charAt(k)-anotherString.charAt(k)

If there is no index position at which they differ, then the shorter string lexicographically precedes the longer string. In this case, compareTo returns the difference of the lengths of the strings -- that is, the value:

this.length()-anotherString.length()"