# Two .compareTo method questions?

Tags: java, string

I searched for a complete table of the lexicographic ordering used in Java, with no avail.

I find collating pattern. But what I need is a ordering that includes letter in upper and lower cases, numbers, operators, space.

I know space is the first in that ordering, what about the rest?

Done of my first question, my 2nd question is:

What exactly does the number returned by `compareTo` method tells you?

For ex. How many letters apart are two letter of the same index of two different words?

Comment: Ask one question per question, please. Also, both of your questions are answered by the Javadocs -- please do research before asking here.

Comment: Lexicographic ordering is basically arbitrary (though fixed). So, why do you need to know what it is? Once you know what it is, you'll probably find it's not the collation you want.

Answer (score 2):

### Part 1

The comparison is based on the Unicode value of each character in the strings. So basically, `compareTo()` treats each string like a sequence of 16-bit unsigned integers. Here is a [Unicode chart](http://unicode-table.com/en/) so you can see what order they come in.

REF: [String.compareTo doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29)

### Part 2

Essentially, there's no telling what the magnitude of the `compareTo` return value is, just the sign. In practice, most `compareTo` implementations will return -1, 0, or 1, but the contract specifically says positive or negative, and you should write your code accordingly (e.g., using `int compare = a.compareTo(b); if(compare > 0) {...} else...)`.

According to [String.compareTo doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29)

> In this case, compareTo returns the difference of the two character values at position k >in the two string -- that is, the value:
>
> ```
> this.charAt(k)-anotherString.charAt(k)
> ```
>
> If there is no index position at which they differ, then the shorter string lexicographically precedes the longer string. In this case, compareTo returns the difference of the lengths of the strings -- that is, the value:
>
> ```
> this.length()-anotherString.length()
> ```

REF: [String Compareto actual return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798890/string-compareto-actual-return-value)

Comment: Was this indeed the information you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You could replace a space with non-ascii code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(
                "pqrst",
                "Abcdef",
                "Lmno",
                " uvw",
                "xyz",
                "Ghijk"
        ));
        Collections.sort(data, new MyDataComparator());
        for (String s : data) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}

class MyDataComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        String regex = " ";
        byte[] b = { (byte) 0x80 };  // out of ascii code
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher m1 = p.matcher(s1);
        Matcher m2 = p.matcher(s2);
        String r1 = m1.replaceAll(new String(b));
        String r2 = m2.replaceAll(new String(b));
        return r1.compareTo(r2);
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
Abcdef
Ghijk
Lmno
pqrst
xyz
 uvw
```