# What does the CompareTo function do in this situation in Java

Tags: java, compare, compareto

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.print("Comparing \"axe\" with \"dog\" produces ");
     // I don't understand what this does.
     int i = "axe".compareTo("dog");
     System.out.println(i);

     System.out.print("Comparing \"applebee's\" with \"apple\" produces ");
     // neither this.
     System.out.println( "applebee's".compareTo("apple") );


}
```

When i run the code it comes up with -3 and the next one is 5,
I don't understand how you can compare letters and it coming up with numbers.
The "applebee" and the "dog" are not even string variables
This is for an assignment at school at [this](http://programmingbydoing.com/a/compareto-challenge.html) link

Comment: http://programmingbydoing.com/a/compareto-challenge.html

Comment: [String#compareTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo-java.lang.String-)

Comment: "I don't understand how you can compare letters and it coming up with numbers" - e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance or basically all sorts of ways you could think of to differentiate strings, e.g. if the lengths differ return the difference, it not then do some more comparison.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String Compareto actual return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798890/string-compareto-actual-return-value)

Comment: Look into the source code, that helps a lot. For example: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#1132 , but you IDE must support "View method source" also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java String class provides the `.compareTo ()` method in order to lexicographically compare Strings.

The return of this method is an `int` which can be interpreted as follows:

- returns `< 0` then the String calling the method is lexicographically first (comes first in a dictionary)
- returns `== 0` then the two strings are lexicographically equivalent
- returns `> 0` then the parameter passed to the compareTo method is lexicographically first.

In your example:

`"axe".compareTo("dog")` return `-3` because `axe` is lexicographically come first in dictionary.

It begins with first character of each string: `a` come before `d` in dictionary.if the compared characters are lexicographically equivalent
it will go to the next characters in the string to compare them and so on.

```
 "applebee's".compareTo("apple")
```

The first 5 characters in first string `"apple"` is lexicographically equivalent to second string but characters `bee's` come after the second string so it will return `5` which is bigger than `0` because second string come first in dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Before practice, my advice is to read the documentation. In this case the Oracle reference clearly explains the reason for positive and negative numbers:

> Compares two strings lexicographically. The comparison is based on the Unicode value of each character in the strings. The character sequence represented by this String object is compared lexicographically to the character sequence represented by the argument string. The result is a negative integer if this String object lexicographically precedes the argument string. The result is a positive integer if this String object lexicographically follows the argument string. The result is zero if the strings are equal; compareTo returns 0 exactly when the equals(Object) method would return true.

And here explains why -**3** and +**5**:

> This is the definition of lexicographic ordering. If two strings are different, then either they have different characters at some index that is a valid index for both strings, or their lengths are different, or both. If they have different characters at one or more index positions, let k be the smallest such index; then the string whose character at position k has the smaller value, as determined by using the < operator, lexicographically precedes the other string. In this case, compareTo returns the difference of the two character values at position k in the two string -- that is, the value:

```
this.charAt(k)-anotherString.charAt(k)
```

> If there is no index position at which they differ, then the shorter
>   string lexicographically precedes the longer string. In this case,
>   compareTo returns the difference of the lengths of the strings that
>   is, the value:

```
this.length()-anotherString.length()
```

Answer (score 0):

The *specific numbers* returned by `compareTo` are an implementation detail you should try not to care about.  The documentation of `compareTo` specifies that all you should care about is the sign: is the number negative (`a.compareTo(b) < 0` implies `a < b`), zero (`a.compareTo(b)` implies `a` is equal to `b`), or positive (`a.compareTo(b) > 0` implies `a > b`).